# Any way to get light image when iPhone is on dark mode?

Tags: ios, ios13, ios-darkmode

```
>             UITraitCollection *lightTrait = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithUserInterfaceStyle:UIUserInterfaceStyleLight];
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:name inBundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] compatibleWithTraitCollection:lightTrait];
```

I want to get the image on light model , regardless of what the current theme of the iOS device is.

But the above code does not seem to work.

Comment: OK, it because the rendering, we should return image with [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal], otherwise image will draw with the system mode。

Answer (score 0):

Odd, I don't see what's wrong with your code.

You can also try the following:

```
let lightImage = image.imageAsset?.image(with: lightTrait)
```

Comment: Thank you, I had solved this by setting the renderingMode.